# Angular 6 with Bulma CSS renders HTML elements without Bulma styling

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I just installed Angular 6, spun up a new app, and added [Bulma](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-bulma) as a CSS framework.

To make sure everything was running correctly, I made a few quick changes to my `app.component.html` template and ran `ng serve`. Here's the HTML.

```
<div class="card" style="margin: 0 auto;">
  <h1>My New App</h1>
  <h3>You have a lot of work to do</h3>
  <ul>
    <li>item 1</li>
    <li>item 2</li>
    <li>
      <ol>
        <li>sub-item 1</li>
        <li>sub-item 2</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The Bulma is fine. Bafflingly, though, the `H1` and `H3`s are rendering like this.

[image: baffling HTML]

Have I missed some basic, fundamental change with Angular 6? Pretty sure HTML should work straight out of the bag.

Here you can see the default Bulma styling crossed out

[image: dev tools shot]

Let me know if you'd like me to post the `app.module.ts` or `app.component.ts`, `package.json`, or `angular.json.` files.

```
#### app.component.css ####

ul {
  list-style: none;
}


#### angular.json ####

...

"styles": [
    "src/styles.css",
    "node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.min.css"
  ]

...
```

Comment: did you add your css to style.css

Comment: I haven't added any CSS. The `h1` and `h3` should default to different sizes.

Comment: Using developer tools what the css of the `h1` and `h3` element? 
in this case you should find the default css rules of `h1`, `h2` and there must be rules overwriting them. or maybe they aren't rendered as `h` for whatever reasons.

Comment: You're right, using dev tools, I can see the `user agent stylesheet` is removing Bulma's default `h1` and `h2` default `size` and `font-weight` properties.

Comment: @John great, then have you solved it so I should at as answer to close the question or still the issue unsolved?

Comment: No. It's not solved. I don't know why user agent stylesheet is overriding my CSS framework. Investigating ...

Comment: @John check your `<!DOCTYPE html>` in the `index.html` AFAIK if it's written incorrectly it causes this weird styling issue

Comment: @k0hamed Checked that. Wasn't it.

Comment: Could you point as to live demo?

Comment: it's not the `user agent stylesheet` which is overwriting it, the image you added tells that it's the `user agent stylesheet ` that is being overwritten, you must find another rule with the value overwriting it, 
the `font-size` to small and `font-weight` to normal

Comment: At least give us `app.component.css`

Comment: There it is. Nothing in there that would affect anything.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so the problem is Bulma itself. It does some strange things with HTML header tags.

You need to wrap `h1` etc. in `<div class="content">` tags. Like this:

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="card" style="margin: 0 auto;">
    <h1>My New App</h1>
    <h3>You have a lot of work to do</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>item 1</li>
      <li>item 2</li>
      <li>
        <ol>
          <li>sub-item 1</li>
          <li>sub-item 2</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

[This Github issue](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/issues/1627) explains further.

[This Bulma documentation](https://bulma.io/documentation/elements/content/) is also helpful.